# Windows 7 - Extreme Long Black Screen After Boot Screen Before Login Screen But Can Load Desktop

Tags: windows-7, boot

So, here is how my computer starts up:

1. BIOS screen
2. short no backlight blackscreen
3. Boot Screen
4. long with backlight blackscreen
5. flash of no blacklight blackscreen
6. Windows 7 login screen loads up

I tried a lot of other ones on web but they doesn't work. Please comment me what information I ought to put in. But now I can tell some:

1. No updates available for my display adapter.
2. 6gbs ram
3. 64 bits system
4. sp1 installed
5. no problem on my registry on Shell in Windows NT HKEY

Comment: A long boot time indicates a driver problem.  When you elminiate most of your statup applications and drivers what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound like it could be the hard drive. Maybe bad sectors, I would update your BIOS and run CHKDSK /R in cmd. Make sure you are an administrator when you run it. to open cmd hit the Windows key+R, then type cmd.

Comment: I scan took half my day, but sure it was faster. But my BIOS has no update, thanks a lot.